# Преобразовать список кортежей в таблицу

Tags: python, строки

Не могу понять как преобразовать список с кортежами в "подобие" таблицы
На входе: `[(1, 'abc', 2000, 'абв'),(2, 'def', 2011, 'где')]`
На выходе:

```
1 | abc | 2000 | абв
2 | def | 2011 | где
```

Comment: А в чем конкретная сложность с пониманием? `print`, например, чем не устраивает?

Comment: вам нужно пройти по списку и вывести каждый из них через `print(' | '.join(map(str, lst)))`.  
ну или так `print(*[' | '.join(map(str, lst)) for lst in my_list], sep='\n')`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Преобразовать кортеж в строку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1416327/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b6-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83)

Comment: @n1tr0xs а это тот же самый товарищ...

Answer (score 1):

Как нибудь так можно

```py
a = [(1, 'abc', 2000, 'абв'),(2, 'def', 2011, 'где')]
result = []
for i in a:
    result.append(" | ".join(map(str, i)))

print("\n".join(result))
```

Вывод

```
1 | abc | 2000 | абв
2 | def | 2011 | где
```

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю использовать pandas для данной задачи. После преобразования далее можешь работать с данными гораздо эффективнее.

```
import pandas as pd

a = [(1, 'abc', 2000, 'абв'),(2, 'def', 2011, 'где')]
pd.DataFrame(a)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]